# Reading input from istringstream, skipping first value C++

Tags: c++, input, operator-overloading

This is for an assignment so I'm not expecting an answer, but a nudge in the right direction is greatly appreciated :)!

We were told to write a Polynomial class to contain a pointer to an array of ints. Each index with a value > 0 will be part of the polynomial such that (value)x^(index), so degrees can only be positive.

My issue is with the test code provided for us, and my overloaded input operator. So the input assumes the first value read is the number of values that will follow, so {5,3,7,-2,1,6} will be 5 values to place in ascending order of degree into the array. So 3 at index 0, 7 at 1, -2 at 2, and so on. The problem is that the first value that I read from my instructors test code is always skipped, and the code breaks once it reads a negative value.

This is the part of his test code that creates the istringstream to input:

```
  int tests[][16] = {
    { 0 },          // 0 (zero polynomial)
    { 1,  1 },      // 1
    { 1, -7 },      // -7
    { 2, 0, 1 },    // x
    { 2, 5, -1 },   // 5 - x
    { 3, 0, 0, 1 }, // x^2
    { 3, 1, -2, 1 }, // x^2 - 2x + 1
    { 3, -1, 0, 1 }, // x^2 - 1
    { 4, 0, 0, 0, 1 }, // x^3
    { 4, 2, -6, 6, -2 }, //
    { 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 }, // 
    { 5, 4, 12, 20, 12, 4 },
    { 5, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1 },
    { 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
    { 6, 1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1 },
    { 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
  };

  int n_tests = 16;

  START_TEST((char*)"Operators");
  // Outer loop (for the first operand 'p')
  for (int i = 0; i < n_tests; i++) {
    int ci[256];
    int ni = tests[i][0];   
    for (int k = 0; k < ni; k++)
      ci[k] = tests[i][k + 1];

    // construct polynomial 'p' by way of the input operator
    char buf[1024] = "";
    for (int k = 0; k < ni; k++) {
      if (ci[k] != 0) 
    sprintf(buf + strlen(buf), "%d %d ", ci[k], k);
    }
    istringstream istr(buf);
    Polynomial p;
    istr >> p;
```

The test loops until it reaches the third set of values (1, -7) and reads -7 first, breaking the code when it tries to resize the array to -7.

This is my overloaded input operator:

```
friend istream& operator >>(istream& input, Polynomial& arr) {

    int coeff = 0;   // holds the coefficient multiplied by the variable
    int nums = 0;    // holds the amount of integers to be input

    input >> nums;   // grab first input value

    if (nums > arr.size) {   // resize array if necessary
        arr.resize(nums);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nums; i++) {  // input coefficients at i index
        input >> coeff;
        arr.set_coeff(i,coeff);
    }
    arr.set_degree();
    arr.isFull();
    return input;
}
```

set_coeff:

```
int Polynomial::set_coeff(unsigned power, int coeff) {

    // resize pArray if power is out of bounds
    if (power >= size) {
        resize(power);
    }

    // insert value and reset attributes
    pArray[power] = coeff;
    set_degree();
    isFull();

    return power;
}
```

Thanks for any help you may have!

Comment: What is the propose of `buf + strlen(buf)` in `sprintf(buf + strlen(buf), "%d %d ", ci[k], k);`?

Comment: @wesley.mesquita I wish I knew... I'm struggling to understand most of what his test code does within itself, I'm just keeping track of what it does with my code :/. I did email him about this as well, but he hasn't responded yet.

Comment: How do you know the code is breaking? What does it do when you enter a negative number?

Comment: @0x499602D2 If the first value is negative, it uses that value to set the size of the array, so it breaks. The assumption is that the first value must be positive, and that value is equal to the number of values that come after it.

Comment: Can you show `set_coeff`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 set_coeff is up

Comment: Change `buf + strlen(buf)` to `buf` please. That's just one mistake I found so far.